# List view inside grid view cell not scrolling

Tags: android, listview, gridview

In my app I want add list view inside grid view cell .But list view inside grid view cell not scrolling . Please provide me appropriate solution to solve this issue .

Comment: As shwn here ou cannot put a listview inside scroll view 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3495890/how-can-i-put-a-listview-into-a-scrollview-without-it-collapsing

Comment: I want to list view inside grid view , not inside scroll view .

Comment: Well i dnt know the solution, but probably gridview already has default scroller, and listview too has one..and as there are two scroller for list view now, that has caused problem.